# Show the default timezone from a date time string in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to pull out the timezone from a string I'm receiving from an API to display it separately. 
After reading a ton of answers none of them seem to cover this simple task I'm trying to do.

The string comes as `2019-01-17T10:00:00-05:00`

1- If I do `echo date('P', $variablecontainingthestring);` it will return +00:00 for some reason.

2- If I do `$datevar = date($variablecontainingstring);` this will return 2019-01-17UTC10:00:00-05:00, doing the same echo as #1 but with the $datevar will also return +00:00 when it is clearly -05:00

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in PHP accepts 2 parameters. The first is the format you want the date to be displayed in, and the second is a unix timestamp. What you would be better of using is the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) class. Then you can get the timezone like this:

```
echo (new \DateTime('2019-01-17T10:00:00-05:00'))->format('P');
```